# tried to emit the INPUT value through OUTPUT but, it doesn't change the flag state

Tags: angular, angular9

my code in 2 components:
Parent:

```js
  openLibraryMenu() {
    this.libraryMenuOpen = true;
    }
```

```html
<section>
Hello Test
<button (click)="openLibraryMenu()">parentButton</button>
</section>

<app-library-section [libraryMenuOpen]="libraryMenuOpen" (hamburgerChecked)='libraryMenuClose($event)'>
</app-library-section>
```

Child Component:

```js
  @Input() libraryMenuOpen: boolean = false;
  @Output() hamburgerChecked = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  
   minimizeMenu() {
    this.libraryMenuOpen = false;
    this.hamburgerChecked.emit(this.libraryMenuOpen);
  }
```

```html
<nav class="libraryMenuNav" *ngIf="libraryMenuOpen">
Body to be rendered
<button (click)="minimizeMenu()">childButton</button>
</nav>
```

When clicked on the parentButton the libraryMenuOpen returns true and opens the block in child. In child when clicked on childButton it returns false and closes the block. BUT, when I click again parentButton it returns true in parent component but doesn't open the child block. 
I want to keep it simple, that's why I am not posting all code. Can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance. Let me know if more data required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use one flag only, in your root component, to show or hide the child component. Your child component only emits the close event and your root component just update the flag.

```
<app-library-section *ngIf="libraryMenuOpen" (hamburgerChecked)="libraryMenuOpen = false">
</app-library-section>
```

Comment: Works fine if I use one flag. Is there any reason it doesn't work if I emit the input value through output. Thanks

Comment: The child component could not detect the change. You should debug the state in the child component before you click again. But this is a better approach.